# Is there a risk installing Win10 printer driver in Win11?

Tags: drivers, windows-11

I need to set up my old Brother MFC-6490CW printer/scanner to run from my new computer under Windows 11 Pro 64. I want to be able to connect via Wi-Fi, if possible.

On the [*Downloads* page for this model](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc6490cw_all), selecting Windows 11 bring up a page on which the most capable package is the *Printer Driver & Scanner Driver for Local Connection*, whose description says, "This download only includes the printer and scanner ... drivers, optimized for USB or Parallel interface. ... To get the most functionality out of your Brother machine, we recommend you install Full Driver & Software Package."

There is no *Full Driver & Software Package* on the Win11 page, but there is on the page for Win10 64, and that is the package I used on my previous computer running Win10.

Brother's [*Windows 11* Support page](https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/175562) has a list of models with Win11 support. The MFC-6490 isn't listed. The page says "If your model is not listed, then we don't have plans to release supported drivers or software. For machines with Windows 10 drivers and software available, you may be able to use it on Windows 11. Though this alternative method may work, we can't guarantee functionality and don't offer support."

Would I be taking a chance by installing the Win10 driver package in Win11? What is the worst that could happen?

If its dangerous to try the Win10 driver, I suppose I could use the Win11 driver and give up the ability to connect by Wi-Fi. But it would be nice to keep Wi-Fi ability if I can do that safely.

Comment: Update: Based on the advice in both answers, I went ahead and installed the Windows 10 driver package. It reported installing successfully and appears to be working perfectly for wireless printing and scanning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would I be taking a chance by installing the Win10 driver package in Win11?

Windows 11 kept the same driver framework as that of Windows 10,
so there is a very high chance that any driver written for Windows 10
will work just as well for Windows 11.

> What is the worst that could happen?

The worst would be to uninstall the package and driver and reinstall
the previous ones.

You could as insurance create a System Restore point
to simplify returning to the current state of Windows in case
that uninstalling/reinstalling will not pass correctly.
This will let you roll Windows back to its state before you
installed the Windows 10 software.

Answer (score 2):

The worst thing that can happen is that, even if you forget doing a **restore point/backup** that is 100% safe and to which you can go back, you can just enter Windows 11 in **safe mode** and uninstall or disable the driver there. Safe mode loads the system with only basic required drivers.

But it is extremely unlikely that printer drivers will completely mess the system up. They would need to be coded quite poorly. They usually don't interact with any system parts that wouldn't let you boot the system normally.

The biggest possibility of failure is that they just won't work or be integrated into the system's UI well. However, Windows 10 and 11 are very similar systems in terms of most parts, so even that isn't too likely.

So there's barely any risk and worst case scenario you would need to do few rather simple fixing steps with help of your phone or another device to access the web.